# Slidedeck Pro Wordpress Image Size

Tags: images, slideshow

I was using Slidedeck pro wordpress (dynamic slider), and set it to pull in the first image from the post's gallery as the image. However, it keeps resizing the image down to 270px when I really need to have the image at 500px. Does anyone know how to remedy this?

I did find a template file with the resizing ratio. However, I am not even sure what to change to achieve the 500px width I need.

```
// Correct image aspect ratio to fit within skin's image constraints
if( !empty( $image ) ){
    if( !empty( $image['width'] ) ){
        if( $image['width'] > 270 ){
            $w_ratio = 270 / $image['width'];
            $image['width'] = floor( $w_ratio * $image['width'] );
            if( isset( $image['height'] ) ) {
                $image['height'] = floor( $w_ratio * $image['height'] );
            }
        }
    }
    if( !empty( $image['height'] ) ){
        if( $image['height'] > 250 ){
            $h_ratio = 250 / $image['height'];
            $image['width'] = floor( $h_ratio * $image['width'] );
            $image['height'] = floor( $h_ratio * $image['height'] );
        }
    }
}
```

I did try changing 270 to 500 earlier to no avail.

Comment: If you're (really) using the "PRO" version, then there's [support available](http://www.slidedeck.com/slidedeck-web-slider-support/)...

Comment: agreed but ill update my answer below

Answer (score 1):

does it have a control panel with sizing options? Is there any mention of 270px at all in the files. If not then either your image is 270px or WordPress is resizing it. If WordPress is doing it check out this page settings>media

**EDIT:**

```
// Correct image aspect ratio to fit within skin's image constraints
if( !empty( $image ) ){
if( !empty( $image['width'] ) ){
    if( $image['width'] > 500 ){
        $w_ratio = 500 / $image['width'];
        $image['width'] = floor( $w_ratio * $image['width'] );
        if( isset( $image['height'] ) ) {
            $image['height'] = floor( $w_ratio * $image['height'] );
        }
    }
}
if( !empty( $image['height'] ) ){
    if( $image['height'] > 250 ){ // Change the 250. This is the height you want so change to your height you use for your images
        $h_ratio = 250 / $image['height']; // Same here change the 250
        $image['width'] = floor( $h_ratio * $image['width'] );
        $image['height'] = floor( $h_ratio * $image['height'] );
    }
}
}
```

Note that if you update the plugin you will have to change this every time. It is best to ask the dev if there are any plans for a control panel or a place to assign custom sizes.

Comment: Yeah, I asked there but it has been 4 days since a response, so I thought I would ask people here.

Comment: did this work at all. if so mark as answered. Also just goes to show that paid plugin support is sometimes not better then free plugin support. I have had the same issue happen on wpmudev

Comment: Oh my apologies. Changing the '270' to '500' didnt work. Somehow it is being overridden somewhere.

Comment: Hi Louis, how did you eventually resolve this issue if ever? I'm trying to tinker with the slides using CSS. Not having any luck.